# How to relate two series(GP and AP) using a positive real number, who have nothing in common?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Here is a question from my book:

> Given a GP and an AP with positive terms $a,a_1,a_2,a_3...a_n$ and $b,b_1,b_2,b_3,...b_n$ respectively. The common ratio of the GP is different from $1$.
>   Then there exists $x\in \Bbb R^+$, such that $\log_xa_n-\log_xa$ is equal to
>
> (A) $a-b$
>   (B) $a_n-b$
>   (C) $b_n-b$
>   (D) $a_n-b_n$

I asked for the solution from my teacher but he said that the question was wrong since there is no relation given between AP and GP. I told him that we can adjust $x$ according to our needs but he wasn't convinced. I hope there is a way to solve this question.
We just have to find out which options aren't possible for any value of $x$.

Above statement is my only progress(if the question is solved I indeed progressed further than my teacher XD).

Thanks for any hints or solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only correct option is $(C)$.

$(A)$ is **not** correct since for $n=1,a=1,a_1=2,b=1,b_1=2$, there does not exist $x\in\mathbb R^+$ such that 
$$\log_x2-\log_x1=0$$

$(B)$ is **not** correct since for $n=1,a=2,a_1=1,b=1,b_1=2$, there does not exist $x\in\mathbb R^+$ such that 
$$\log_x1-\log_x2=0$$

For $(C)$, we see that $$\log_x a_n-\log_x a=b_n-b$$
is equivalent to
$$\ln x=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{a_n}{a}\right)}{b_n-b}\tag1$$
where we always have $b_n-b=nd\not=0$ assuming that the common difference $d$ is not $0$.

Note here that the range of the function $y=\ln x$ is $\mathbb R$. So, for *every real number* $c$, there exists $x\in\mathbb R^+$ such that $\ln x=c$. So, there exists $x\in\mathbb R^+$ such that $(1)$. Hence, the option $(C)$ is correct.

$(D)$ is **not** correct since for $n=1,a=1,a_1=2,b=1,b_1=2$, there does not exist $x\in\mathbb R^+$ such that 
$$\log_x2-\log_x1=0$$

Comment: Thanks, I would accept your answer. But is there any way to prove that option C is correct. Well there is a fault that it is not mentioned that AP's common difference isn't 0. Leaving it aside can you prove option C.

Comment: @Love Invariants: I've added some explanations.